# Programming to get data from EV3 sensor and send it to a server?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

I am using EV3 with Linux V1.09 and I am doing a project in which I want to send the sensor data from the EV3 to a remote web server using POST method - is this possible?

Comment: You can use CURL for generating post requests. Provided you have the data in a readable, parse-able format (full disclosure, I've never used mindstorms so I don't know if this is actually relevant.)
https://curl.haxx.se/

Answer (score 1):

Another possible method is to use I2C to communicate from the EV3 to an Arduino with a WiFi shield or module, then have the Arduino perform the POST.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

If you are using the official LEGO firmware, you will need a computer that reads data from the EV3 using direct commands, then relays that information to the web server.

The EV3 could send the information directly if you use a 3rd party OS for EV3, such as ev3dev or leJOS.